# Execution/Access of deployed django(python) web application on server is not working

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, server

I am newbie to django/python, I have developed django application and uploaded it on linux server, after uploading i have successfully deployed the app on server, there are no errors in deployment, Now i want to access that application through web browser but it is not working. It says "This site can’t be reached, it took so long to respond", I don't understand where i am wrong, where the problem is. Please suggest some solution.
Thanks.

Python 3.5 and django 2.2 i have used for app development, i have used nginx and uWSGI with deployment

python3 manage.py check --deploy to deploy the app and it is successfully deployed

I am expecting to access that application on web browser but I got 
"This site can’t be reached 206.81.11.228 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: There's no way we can help you unless you post your nginx and uwsgi configuration

Comment: @DanielRoseman: can you tell me how can i check nginx and uwsgi configuration, so that i can send you both configuration to check, i have executed some commands and write out two files for sure . thanks

Comment: But you said you used nginx and uwsgi. How did you set them up?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I have used "sudo apt-get install nginx mysql-server python3-pip python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev ufw virtualenv" for nginx setup and "pip install uwsgi" for uwsgi, and may be few more as i was surfing on google for the solutions

Comment: That is just installing them. How did you configure them to actually serve the Django site?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html i have referred given link and followed the steps mentioned in it, if i need to perform anything more than mentioned in link, kindly guide me regarding that. i will surely follow your steps.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Please help me

Comment: I can't help until you show your nginx and uwsgi configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - nginx configuration is as below ->
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 127.0.0.1;
       location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

       location = /static/ {
         root /home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app;
       }
       location = /media/ {
         root /home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app;
       }

       location = / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app.sock;
       }
     }

Comment: You should put that in the question. But straight away we can see that the server is only listening on 127.0.0.1, not 206.81.11.228.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Now i have changed nginx configuration as below
server {
       listen 8000;
       server_name 206.81.11.228;
       location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

       location = /static/ {
         root /home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app;
       }
       location = /media/ {
         root /home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app;
       }

       location = / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/root/Azyaan/Azyaan/Azyaan_app.sock;
       }
     }

But still i'm unable to access it, using mentioned ip or domain

Answer (score -1):

That server only have 2 ports opened (80 and 443) with apache running behind. If your django project is really running, then you should open the django port in your firewall.

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 8000/tcp
# systemctl restart firewalld
```

Comment: OP didn't say anything about running Django on port 8000.

Comment: @Abs - This didn't work, it is preventing other project's request on server.

Comment: I set 8000 as example because it is the default port when running django. My answer works only for Redhat/Centos systems. If @TestUpdates is using Ubuntu,  the firewall could be **ufw**, which need a different way to open ports. If the uwsgi is running, and it cannot be accessed from outside, blocked ports may be is the problem.